# Density plots via Map with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe `df` in R. (We can use the example of `iris`.) I also have simple transformations of iris:

```
iris0 <- iris
iris1 <- cbind(log(iris[,1:4]),iris[5])
iris2 <- cbind(sqrt(iris[,1:4]),iris[5])
```

I want to create a list object containing the density distributions of all numerical attributes in `iris`, for each of these three datasets. (So, in total 4 attributes for each of 3 datasets: 12 density plots in one list object.) I would like the densities from a given dataset (for each attribute) to all be a single colour, i.e. the colour should depend purely on the dataset. Using just base R, I thought Map would be the best way to do it:

```
datasets=c("iris0","iris1","iris2")
Map(function(.x, .y, df) {
  ggplot(data = get(df), aes(x=.x)) +
  geom_density(aes(fill=df)) + xlab(.y) + ggtitle(label=paste0(.y," Density in ",df," dataset"))}, df[names(df)], names(df), as.character(datasets) )
```

This seems to run into an error, `Error in get(df) : object 'df' not found`. I also tried wrapping the `df[names(df)]` and `names(df)` with `get` around each `df`, but the error persisted.

I can also see other potential problems down the line--I'm not sure `fill=df` will correctly encode the data-frames as a factor and ensure they are a separate unique colour each (but each remain the same colour for all attributes).

Can anyone help solve this one?

(I would like to do it without using any packages besides base R + ggplot2 and potentially dplyr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Map` I make use of `lapply` to first iterate over the `datasets` and second over the variables via `names(get(df))[1:4]` At the end I flatten the list of lists using `Reduce`. I also added a custom palette to fill the density plots by dataset. Try this:

```r
iris0 <- iris
iris1 <- cbind(log(iris[,1:4]),iris[5])
iris2 <- cbind(sqrt(iris[,1:4]),iris[5])

datasets <- c("iris0","iris1","iris2")
palfill <- c("iris0" = "red","iris1" = "green","iris2" = "blue")

library(ggplot2)

# list of lists
plots <- lapply(datasets, function(df) {
  lapply(names(get(df))[1:4], function(.x) {
    ggplot(data = get(df), aes_string(x = .x)) +
      geom_density(aes(fill = df)) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = palfill) +
      xlab(.x) +
      ggtitle(label = paste0(.x, " Density in ", df," dataset"))
  })
})
# flatten
plots <- Reduce(c, plots)

plots[[1]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly (and though I didn't ask, easily enough extended to datasets with different numbers of numerical columns). I am wondering, is there any way to do the colours without specifying ```palfill <- c("iris0" = "red","iris1" = "green","iris2" = "blue")```. So then I could use a nice R palette (rather than my own poor creative choices) and not have to specify the exact length of the dataset either

Comment: I tried replacing ```scale_fill_manual(values = palfill)``` with ```scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral")``` but it just results in every plot having the same colour

Comment: For sure. Try `palfill <- setNames(brewer.pal(length(datasets), "Spectral"), datasets)`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!